# Individaul Asserts passes, but Assert at class instance fails

Tags: c#, vs-unit-testing-framework

My class definition is as below:

```
  public class Testing
{
    public string account, order_id;
    public DateTime process_dt, exec_dt;
}
```

Have 2 instances of the same class. My goal is to compare these 2 instances and if it passes, my test passes. Because of the dateTime fields, before the assertion I overwrite the time to a Date field so that the ticks match using:

```
exp.process_dt = exp.process_dt.Date;
act.process_dt = act.process_dt.Date;
exp.exec_dt = exp.exec_dt.Date;
act.exec_dt = act.exec_dt.Date;
```

If I do individual asserts on all the class fields, all of them pass. But if I do a assert using class objects or Serialize the objects and do a compare, it always returns False.

```
 Assert.AreEqual(actual, expData);
```

Could you guide me to What I am missing, any idea why individual asserts pass, but object asserts and Serialization matching fails. 
Note: in the DateTime fields: InternalKind,Kind,DateData values don't match. InternalTicks and Ticks match.

Language C#.

Comment: Does that class override Equals()?

Comment: @vyrp. No it doesn't. That was the first problem. Thanks much for pointing that out. Implemented the Equals override manually as one approach.After some digging - found that the date fields have a Z as a differentiator. Resolved this and the object comparison works.  I ended up using Object comparison using serialization and then doing an Asser on the value returned by this comparison